# Unable to retrieve camera characteristics for unknown device

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm receiving reports from some of my users with the following exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: getCameraCharacteristics:1019:
> Unable to retrieve camera characteristics for unknown device 0: No
> such file or directory (-2) at
> android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1591)
> at
> android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(CameraManager.java:693)

This is of course doesn't make any sense, because we all know that the camera at "0" id should be available. And I have the info about cameras of a device being included to the report anyway:

```
Camera ID: 0 (selected), all [0, 2, 1, 3]
Cameras level: FULL, LIMITED, LIMITED, LIMITED
```

So it seems from time to time system thinks that such camera is not available and triggers this annoying exception.

One thing I can say that this issue only happened for Android 12...

**UPDATE** the issue seems to be related to this one [Android camera recording is not working in background mode for some newest smartphones on Android 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943752/android-camera-recording-is-not-working-in-background-mode-for-some-newest-smart)