# Android camera recording is not working in background mode for some newest smartphones on Android 12

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

To record video from camera in background mode I use something like this (`MediaCodec`, `Camera2` APIs):

```
// record stuff
val recorderSurface = MediaCodec.createPersistentInputSurface()
...

// configure camera using camera2 API
val surfaces = ArrayList<Surface>().apply {
    // holder of SurfaceView
    // only used when app in foreground, if in background it will be null
    holder?.let { add(it.surface) } 

    add(recorderSurface) // it is used in background and foreground (always)
}

val captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice
    .createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD).apply {
        surfaces.forEach { addTarget(it) }
    }
```

It works fine for almost all devices from Android 6 up to Android 12

It is working fine for my Samsung S10 on Android 12 in both foreground and background modes

But on some more modern/newest devices like Samsung S22 Ultra (also Android 12) it works only in foreground mode fine (when app is visible to a user), in background Camera2 API triggers exceptions, because the system closes the camera right away when trying to record in background. It triggers [`CameraDevice.StateCallback#ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.StateCallback#ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE) error

This is so weird. Because it works fine for most other devices on Android 12.

Any idea what is wrong with such devices? What could have changed...

Comment: Just checking what other devices you tested, and confirming that you aren't encountering any chimera like power management issue: https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung

Comment: @MorrisonChang I disabled battery optimization for my app on Samsung S22 ultra right away but still it didn't help. But Samsung S10 also has Android 12, same version of OneUI, and it works fine for this device, so there is something else

Comment: Nothing weird - old devices upgraded to new system usually lack some features that new devices have out of the box. Seems like user privacy protection. Lots of background things were axed in Android 11, and S10 came out with Pie.

Comment: @Agent_L it has nothing to do with Android and its versions, because officially it is still allowed to use camera in background by implementing it in a foreground service, even for Android 12